# Choosing the right pattern for filter large arrays - Rest vs Local Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs, sqlite

Which is the best approach for an app that aims to filter data, like 5000+ records, by keeping the response speed in focus?

1. Filter local memory arrays
2. Query to db through http API request calls

For my app I use angularjs, php and SQLite3. Right now I load all record from slite db to my table and then filter this field by search. All works great, but when I exceed 3000 records I notice a certain slowing down. By limiting the search on two fields, I get better performance.
My doubt is if changing the model and querying the db I get a better performance or not.

1. Local array advantages

- I can use JavaScript Array map() Method
- low consuming data bandwidth
- I can see all records in table before filter
- I can work, after loading data, in offline.

2. Local array disadvantages

- slowing down performance over 2000 record.

So can you help me to evaluate advantages and disadvantages if I make http API call for any filter action request keeping in focus the performances?

Comment: what about doing the filtering with the SQL query, what's stopping you to do that

Comment: It's a pretty broad questions that depends on a lot of external factors — most importantly: are query results of +2000 the norm or exception? what is the network speed of your user? To they need to work off line? etc. I'm not sure we can really answer this question.

Comment: Hi @VelimirTchatchevsky bandwidth consuming and not sure if performance will be better, for now, stop me do that.

Comment: @MarkMeyer can be the norm, they don't need to work offline, i can't know they connection speed. this is my dilemma

Comment: To put the array in memory you'll have to transfer a lot of data from your persistent storage to PHP.  I/O tends to be the biggest time-sink in PHP scripts so the initial data load will probably hurt performance more than fetching data on demand would.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell about caching in PHP, but for the AngularJS end, there's an approach you can follow:

1. When the user searches for the first time, fetch the result(s) from db.
2. Make 2 copies of the data: one presented to the user directly, another can be stores in a local json with a key value pair approach.
   3.Next time the user searches for anything, look into the local json first for the result. If the data is present locally, no need for the db query, else make the db query and repeat step 2.

The idea is not to make user wait for every search, you cannot simply call all 5000+ records at once and store locally, and you definitely cannot make db queries every-time since RDMS having that much records simply have low performance issues.
So this seems best to me.

Comment: Thks @Abhishek for you time. This is a good compromise. I will try your suggest way